# Error when trying to make soap request to Amadeus Web Service

Tags: php, xml, soap, amadeus

I have xml file with soap header and body.
How I can make request to Amdeus WebService?

In my xml file I have "Action" field

```
<add:Action xmlns:add="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">http://webservices.amadeus.com/Hotel_MultiSingleAvailability_10.0</add:Action>` and "To" field ` <add:To xmlns:add="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">https://nodeD1.test.webservices.amadeus.com/1ASIWOTANA8</add:To>
```

What I should use? Soap Client or something else?

When I send request to SoapClient class

```
$client = new SoapClient("https://nodeD1.test.webservices.amadeus.com/1ASIWOTANA8");
```

I get an error

> SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'https://nodeD1.test.webservices.amadeus.com/1ASIWOTANA8' : failed to load external entity "https://nodeD1.test.webservices.amadeus.com/1ASIWOTANA8"

but if I use browser I get the response.

Comment: Hi, if you are looking at implementing the Amadeus Web Services SOAP interface in PHP, perhaps you'll be interested in a PHP composer package which does this (and more) for you: https://github.com/amabnl/amadeus-ws-client

Comment: @DerMika - Can you please look into this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52090327/how-to-solve-these-erros-in-web-service-and-ajax