# How To Solve These Erros In Web Service And Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, web-services, amadeus

I am creating a web site using the Amadeus Web Service. I have created a SOAP and tested by using SOAP UI. And I got the complete response. After that I tried to get response in web browser. Then I created a below files. But, when I input all the data and clicks the Search button, it gives me these 2 errors -

> OPTIONS https://noded1.test.webservices.amadeus.com/XXXXX 500
>   (Other Error) Failed to load
>   https://noded1.test.webservices.amadeus.com/XXXXX: Response for
>   preflight has invalid HTTP status code 500.

How can I Fix these errors ??

Here is the PHP file.

```
<html>
<head>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.12.0/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://www.timestampgenerator.com/js/common.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

            <form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="#" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="signupForm">

                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 hero-feature"> <!-- Start Of The Col Class -->
                    Message Id : <input class="form-control" id="messageid" type="text" placeholder="Results will be placed here..." readonly size="40"/> <br>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 hero-feature"> <!-- Start Of The Col Class -->
                    Nonce : <input class="form-control" id="nonceshow" type="text"/> <br>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 hero-feature"> <!-- Start Of The Col Class -->
                    Timestamp : <input class="form-control" type="text" name="timestampama" id="timestampama"/> <br>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 hero-feature"> <!-- Start Of The Col Class -->
                    Text : <input type="text" class="form-control" name="strex" id="strex" size="20" />  <br>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 hero-feature"> <!-- Start Of The Col Class -->
                    SHA-1 : <input type="text" class="form-control" name="strcrypt" id="strcrypt" size="33" /> <br>
                </div>

                <a href="#" id="ghsubmitbtn" class="btn btn-success">Search</a>

                <p id="errorModal"></p> <br>

                <div id="ghapidata" class="clearfix"></div>

            </form>

            <p id="body"></p>

            <script type="text/javascript">

            //Main Function
                $(document).ready(function () {

                    $.getScript("PwJs.js", function () {
                    });

                $('#ghsubmitbtn').on('click', function(e) {
                        var country = $('#country').val();
                        var year = $('#year').val();
                        var month = $('#month').val();

                        var messageid = guid();
                        //var nonce = nonceid();
                        //var nonceremove = nonce.slice(0, -4); //Remove last 4 characters
                        //var n = nonceremove.length; //Length
                        var pw = 'SSSSSS';

                        var str = '<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:sec="http://xml.amadeus.com/2010/06/Security_v1" xmlns:typ="http://xml.amadeus.com/2010/06/Types_v1" xmlns:iat="http://www.iata.org/IATA/2007/00/IATA2010.1" xmlns:app="http://xml.amadeus.com/2010/06/AppMdw_CommonTypes_v3" xmlns:link="http://wsdl.amadeus.com/2010/06/ws/Link_v1" xmlns:ses="http://xml.amadeus.com/2010/06/Session_v3" xmlns:fmp="http://xml.amadeus.com/FMPTBQ_14_3_1A">' +
    '<soapenv:Header>' +
        '<add:MessageID xmlns:add="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">' + messageid + '</add:MessageID>' +
        '<add:Action xmlns:add="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">http://webservices.amadeus.com/ZZZZZ</add:Action>' +
        '<add:To xmlns:add="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">https://nodeD1.test.webservices.amadeus.com/XXXXXX</add:To>' +
        '<link:TransactionFlowLink xmlns:link="http://wsdl.amadeus.com/2010/06/ws/Link_v1"/>' +
        '<oas:Security xmlns:oas="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">' +
            '<oas:UsernameToken oas1:Id="UsernameToken-1" xmlns:oas1="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">' +
                '<oas:Username>WSEOLMTT</oas:Username>' +
                '<oas:Nonce EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">' + noncemove + '</oas:Nonce>' +
                '<oas:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordDigest">' + hashedPw + '</oas:Password>' +
                '<oas1:Created>' + timestampama + '</oas1:Created>' +
            '</oas:UsernameToken>' +
        '</oas:Security>' +
        '<AMA_SecurityHostedUser xmlns="http://xml.amadeus.com/2010/06/Security_v1">' +
            '<UserID AgentDutyCode="SU" POS_Type="1" PseudoCityCode="CMBI228AJ" RequestorType="U"/>' +
        '</AMA_SecurityHostedUser>' +
    '</soapenv:Header>' +
    '<soapenv:Body>' +
        '<Fare_MasterPricerTravelBoardSearch>' +
            '<numberOfUnit xmlns="http://xml.amadeus.com/FMPTBQ_14_3_1A">' +
                '<unitNumberDetail>' +
                    '<numberOfUnits>1</numberOfUnits>' +
                    '<typeOfUnit>PX</typeOfUnit>' +
                '</unitNumberDetail>' +
                '<unitNumberDetail>' +
                    '<numberOfUnits>250</numberOfUnits>' +
                    '<typeOfUnit>RC</typeOfUnit>' +
                '</unitNumberDetail>' +
            '</numberOfUnit>' +
            '<paxReference>' +
                '<ptc>ADT</ptc>' +
                '<traveller>' +
                    '<ref>1</ref>' +
                '</traveller>' +
            '</paxReference>' +
            '<fareOptions>' +
                '<pricingTickInfo>' +
                    '<pricingTicketing>' +
                        '<priceType>ET</priceType>' +
                        '<priceType>TAC</priceType>' +
                        '<priceType>RP</priceType>' +
                    '</pricingTicketing>' +
                '</pricingTickInfo>' +
            '</fareOptions>' +
            '<itinerary>' +
                '<requestedSegmentRef>' +
                    '<segRef>1</segRef>' +
                '</requestedSegmentRef>' +
                '<departureLocalization>' +
                    '<departurePoint>' +
                        '<locationId>DEL</locationId>' +
                    '</departurePoint>' +
                '</departureLocalization>' +
                '<arrivalLocalization>' +
                    '<arrivalPointDetails>' +
                        '<locationId>BOM</locationId>' +
                    '</arrivalPointDetails>' +
                '</arrivalLocalization>' +
                '<timeDetails>' +
                    '<firstDateTimeDetail>' +
                        '<date>161018</date>' +
                    '</firstDateTimeDetail>' +
                '</timeDetails>' +
                '<flightInfo>' +
                    '<cabinId>' +
                        '<cabin>Y</cabin>' +
                    '</cabinId>' +
                '</flightInfo>' +
            '</itinerary>' +
        '</Fare_MasterPricerTravelBoardSearch>' +
    '</soapenv:Body>' +
'</soapenv:Envelope>';

                        //console.log(departureDate);

                        $.ajax({
                            url: 'https://nodeD1.test.webservices.amadeus.com/XXXXXX',
                            method: 'POST',
                            contentType:"text/xml; charset=utf-8",
                            data: str,
                            //headers: {"Authorization": 'Bearer ' + bat},
                            beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                                xhr.setRequestHeader('SOAPAction', 'http://webservices.amadeus.com/ZZZZZ');
                                                        },

                            success: function (data) {

                                console.log(data);

                            }

                        });

                    });

                });

            </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is the JavaScript File.

```
//Nonce
            function nonceid() {
              var text = "";
              var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";

              for (var n = 0; n < 12; n++)
                text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));

              return btoa(text).slice(0, -4);
            }
            var n = nonceid().length; //Length
            var noncemove = nonceid();
            console.log("Nonce - " +noncemove);
            console.log("Nonce Characters - " +n);

            document.getElementById('ghsubmitbtn').addEventListener('click', function() {
            document.getElementById('nonceshow').value = nonceid();
            })

            //Timestamp
            var timestampama = new Date().toISOString();
            console.log("Timestamp - " +timestampama);
            console.log(new Date());

            document.getElementById('ghsubmitbtn').addEventListener('click', function() {
            document.getElementById('timestampama').value = timestampama;
            })

            //register onclick events for Encrypt button

            document.getElementById('ghsubmitbtn').addEventListener('click', function() {
            document.getElementById('strcrypt').value = completepw;
            })

            /* document.getElementById('ghsubmitbtn').onclick = function() {
            var txt_string = document.getElementById('strex').value;    // gets data from input text

            //encrypts data and adds it in #strcrypt element
            document.getElementById('strcrypt').value = completepw;
            console.log("SHA1 - " +SHA1(txt_string));
            return false;
            } */

            //SHA1

            function rotate_left(n,s) {
                    var t4 = ( n<<s ) | (n>>>(32-s));
                    return t4;
            }

            function lsb_hex(val) {
                    var str="";
                    var i;
                    var vh;
                    var vl;
                    for( i=0; i<=6; i+=2 ) {
                        vh = (val>>>(i*4+4))&0x0f;
                        vl = (val>>>(i*4))&0x0f;
                        str += vh.toString(16) + vl.toString(16);
                    }
                    return str;
            }

            function cvt_hex(val) {
                    var str="";
                    var i;
                    var v;
                    for( i=7; i>=0; i-- ) {
                        v = (val>>>(i*4))&0x0f;
                        str += v.toString(16);
                    }
                    return str;
            }

            function SHA1 (msg) {

                function Utf8Encode(string) {
                    string = string.replace(/\r\n/g,"\n");
                    var utftext = "";
                    for (var n = 0; n < string.length; n++) {
                        var c = string.charCodeAt(n);
                        if (c < 128) {
                            utftext += String.fromCharCode(c);
                        }
                        else if((c > 127) && (c < 2048)) {
                            utftext += String.fromCharCode((c >> 6) | 192);
                            utftext += String.fromCharCode((c & 63) | 128);
                        }
                        else {
                            utftext += String.fromCharCode((c >> 12) | 224);
                            utftext += String.fromCharCode(((c >> 6) & 63) | 128);
                            utftext += String.fromCharCode((c & 63) | 128);
                        }
                    }
                    return utftext;
                };
                var blockstart;
                var i, j;
                var W = new Array(80);
                var H0 = 0x67452301;
                var H1 = 0xEFCDAB89;
                var H2 = 0x98BADCFE;
                var H3 = 0x10325476;
                var H4 = 0xC3D2E1F0;
                var A, B, C, D, E;
                var temp;
                msg = Utf8Encode(msg);
                var msg_len = msg.length;
                var word_array = new Array();
                for( i=0; i<msg_len-3; i+=4 ) {
                    j = msg.charCodeAt(i)<<24 | msg.charCodeAt(i+1)<<16 |
                    msg.charCodeAt(i+2)<<8 | msg.charCodeAt(i+3);
                    word_array.push( j );
                }
                switch( msg_len% 4 ) {
                    case 0:
                        i = 0x080000000;
                    break;
                    case 1:
                        i = msg.charCodeAt(msg_len-1)<<24 | 0x0800000;
                    break;
                    case 2:
                        i = msg.charCodeAt(msg_len-2)<<24 | msg.charCodeAt(msg_len-1)<<16 | 0x08000;
                    break;
                    case 3:
                        i = msg.charCodeAt(msg_len-3)<<24 | msg.charCodeAt(msg_len-2)<<16 | msg.charCodeAt(msg_len-1)<<8    | 0x80;
                    break;
                }
                word_array.push( i );
                while( (word_array.length% 16)!= 14 ) word_array.push( 0 );
                word_array.push( msg_len>>>29 );
                word_array.push( (msg_len<<3)&0x0ffffffff );
                for ( blockstart=0; blockstart<word_array.length; blockstart+=16 ) {
                    for( i=0; i<16; i++ ) W[i] = word_array[blockstart+i];
                    for( i=16; i<=79; i++ ) W[i] = rotate_left(W[i-3] ^ W[i-8] ^ W[i-14] ^ W[i-16], 1);
                    A = H0;
                    B = H1;
                    C = H2;
                    D = H3;
                    E = H4;
                    for( i= 0; i<=19; i++ ) {
                        temp = (rotate_left(A,5) + ((B&C) | (~B&D)) + E + W[i] + 0x5A827999) & 0x0ffffffff;
                        E = D;
                        D = C;
                        C = rotate_left(B,30);
                        B = A;
                        A = temp;
                    }
                    for( i=20; i<=39; i++ ) {
                        temp = (rotate_left(A,5) + (B ^ C ^ D) + E + W[i] + 0x6ED9EBA1) & 0x0ffffffff;
                        E = D;
                        D = C;
                        C = rotate_left(B,30);
                        B = A;
                        A = temp;
                    }
                    for( i=40; i<=59; i++ ) {
                        temp = (rotate_left(A,5) + ((B&C) | (B&D) | (C&D)) + E + W[i] + 0x8F1BBCDC) & 0x0ffffffff;
                        E = D;
                        D = C;
                        C = rotate_left(B,30);
                        B = A;
                        A = temp;
                    }
                    for( i=60; i<=79; i++ ) {
                        temp = (rotate_left(A,5) + (B ^ C ^ D) + E + W[i] + 0xCA62C1D6) & 0x0ffffffff;
                        E = D;
                        D = C;
                        C = rotate_left(B,30);
                        B = A;
                        A = temp;
                    }
                    H0 = (H0 + A) & 0x0ffffffff;
                    H1 = (H1 + B) & 0x0ffffffff;
                    H2 = (H2 + C) & 0x0ffffffff;
                    H3 = (H3 + D) & 0x0ffffffff;
                    H4 = (H4 + E) & 0x0ffffffff;
                }
                var temp = cvt_hex(H0) + cvt_hex(H1) + cvt_hex(H2) + cvt_hex(H3) + cvt_hex(H4);
                return temp.toUpperCase();
            }

            function SHA1Bytes (msg) {
                var blockstart;
                var i, j;
                var W = new Array(80);
                var H0 = 0x67452301;
                var H1 = 0xEFCDAB89;
                var H2 = 0x98BADCFE;
                var H3 = 0x10325476;
                var H4 = 0xC3D2E1F0;
                var A, B, C, D, E;
                var temp;
                var msg_len = msg.length;
                var word_array = new Array();
                for( i=0; i<msg_len-3; i+=4 ) {
                  if (msg[i] > 255 || msg[i+1] > 255 || msg[i+2] > 255 || msg[i+3] > 255) alert('Not a byte!');
                    j = msg[i]<<24 | msg[i+1]<<16 |
                    msg[i+2]<<8 | msg[i+3];
                    word_array.push( j );
                }
                switch( msg_len% 4 ) {
                    case 0:
                        i = 0x080000000;
                    break;
                    case 1:
                        i = msg[msg_len-1]<<24 | 0x0800000;
                    break;
                    case 2:
                        i = msg[msg_len-2]<<24 | msg[msg_len-1]<<16 | 0x08000;
                    break;
                    case 3:
                        i = msg[msg_len-3]<<24 | msg[msg_len-2]<<16 | msg[msg_len-1]<<8    | 0x80;
                    break;
                }
                word_array.push( i );
                while( (word_array.length% 16)!= 14 ) word_array.push( 0 );
                word_array.push( msg_len>>>29 );
                word_array.push( (msg_len<<3)&0x0ffffffff );
                for ( blockstart=0; blockstart<word_array.length; blockstart+=16 ) {
                    for( i=0; i<16; i++ ) W[i] = word_array[blockstart+i];
                    for( i=16; i<=79; i++ ) W[i] = rotate_left(W[i-3] ^ W[i-8] ^ W[i-14] ^ W[i-16], 1);
                    A = H0;
                    B = H1;
                    C = H2;
                    D = H3;
                    E = H4;
                    for( i= 0; i<=19; i++ ) {
                        temp = (rotate_left(A,5) + ((B&C) | (~B&D)) + E + W[i] + 0x5A827999) & 0x0ffffffff;
                        E = D;
                        D = C;
                        C = rotate_left(B,30);
                        B = A;
                        A = temp;
                    }
                    for( i=20; i<=39; i++ ) {
                        temp = (rotate_left(A,5) + (B ^ C ^ D) + E + W[i] + 0x6ED9EBA1) & 0x0ffffffff;
                        E = D;
                        D = C;
                        C = rotate_left(B,30);
                        B = A;
                        A = temp;
                    }
                    for( i=40; i<=59; i++ ) {
                        temp = (rotate_left(A,5) + ((B&C) | (B&D) | (C&D)) + E + W[i] + 0x8F1BBCDC) & 0x0ffffffff;
                        E = D;
                        D = C;
                        C = rotate_left(B,30);
                        B = A;
                        A = temp;
                    }
                    for( i=60; i<=79; i++ ) {
                        temp = (rotate_left(A,5) + (B ^ C ^ D) + E + W[i] + 0xCA62C1D6) & 0x0ffffffff;
                        E = D;
                        D = C;
                        C = rotate_left(B,30);
                        B = A;
                        A = temp;
                    }
                    H0 = (H0 + A) & 0x0ffffffff;
                    H1 = (H1 + B) & 0x0ffffffff;
                    H2 = (H2 + C) & 0x0ffffffff;
                    H3 = (H3 + D) & 0x0ffffffff;
                    H4 = (H4 + E) & 0x0ffffffff;
                }
                var temp = cvt_hex(H0) + cvt_hex(H1) + cvt_hex(H2) + cvt_hex(H3) + cvt_hex(H4);
                return temp.toUpperCase();
            }

            var gHexa = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'];
            var keyStr = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=";

                function encode64Bytes(input) {
                var output = '';
                var chr1, chr2, chr3;
                var enc1, enc2, enc3, enc4;
                var i = 0;
                while (i < input.length) {
                                chr1 = input[i++];
                                chr2 = input[i++];
                                chr3 = input[i++];
                                enc1 = chr1 >> 2;
                                enc2 = ((chr1 & 3) << 4) | (chr2 >> 4);
                                enc3 = ((chr2 & 15) << 2) | (chr3 >> 6);
                                enc4 = chr3 & 63;
                                if (isNaN(chr2)) {
                                                enc3 = enc4 = 64;
                                } else if (isNaN(chr3)) {
                                                enc4 = 64;
                                }
                                output = output + keyStr.charAt(enc1) + keyStr.charAt(enc2) + keyStr.charAt(enc3) + keyStr.charAt(enc4);
                                }
                                return output;
                                }

                function parseHexaBytes(iText) {
                    var aResult = [];
                    for (var i=0; i < iText.length; i = i+2)
                    {
                      var aValue = parseInt(iText.substr(i, 2), 16);
                      //if (aValue > 255) alert('Too large!');
                      //if (aValue == 0) alert('Null value!');
                      aResult.push(aValue);
                    }
                    return aResult;
                }

                function stringToArray(iText) {
                  var aResult = [];
                  for (var i=0; i < iText.length; i = i+1)
                  {
                    aResult.push(iText.charCodeAt(i));
                  }
                  return aResult;
                }

            var pw = 'SSSSS';
            var clearpw = 'AAAAA';

            //Verify SHA1
            var noncee = 'WnMwUUlVSkQ=';
            var timestampamae = '2018-08-28T09:24:10:030Z';
            var pwe = '123';
            var shapwe = noncee+ ' + ' +timestampamae+ ' + ' +pwe; //5 + 6 + 123

            // Base64 ( SHA-1 ( nonce + created + SHA-1 ( password ) ) )
            var shapw = noncemove+ ' + ' +timestampama+ ' + ' +pw;
            console.log("SHA1 Pw - " +SHA1(shapw));
            console.log("SHA1Bytes Pw - " +SHA1Bytes(shapwe));

            var completepw = btoa(SHA1(shapw));
            console.log("Comple Pw - " +completepw);

            var completepwWithAma = btoa(encode64Bytes(shapwe));
            console.log("Complete Pws Ama Code - " +completepwWithAma);

            function WbsPassword(clearpw,timestampama,noncemove) {
            var aPwd = parseHexaBytes(SHA1(clearpw));
            var aNonce = decode64Bytes(noncemove);
            var aTime = stringToArray(timestampama);
            var aHash = SHA1Bytes(aNonce.concat(aTime.concat(aPwd)));
            var HshPwd = encode64Bytes(parseHexaBytes(aHash));
            return HshPwd;
        }

        var hashedPw = WbsPassword(clearpw,timestampama,noncemove);
        console.log(WbsPassword("WbsPassword - " +clearpw,timestampama,noncemove));
        console.log("hashedPw - " +hashedPw);
```

Comment: Error 500 is a server error. One of your problems from looking over your code quickly, is that your are making some http requests and then some https requests as well. Making http requests on a https connection will throw an internal server error (500). So firstly, make sure that all of your requests are https.

Comment: Please ALWAYS search your error message before asking: https://www.google.nl/search?q=Response+for+preflight+has+invalid+HTTP+status+code+500.+site:stackoverflow.com

Comment: The answer is that your server likely does not support OPTIONS calls

Comment: @Martin - Then should I use https:// inside the Soap Envelope ??

Comment: @mplungjan - I tried each and every articles and sites. But, no luck.. :/

Comment: @Amithash It's worth a shot. I would honestly change all of your links to https instead of http. If the problem persists, it could be because of the external sources not being available in a https format.

Comment: @Martin - This web service is created by Amadeus company. Then I am not able to change http:// to https://. Is there any thing that I can do ??

Comment: @Amithash Not that I know of, sorry :/ - but it's my initial thought that http requests are being made on a https connection, which results in the error.